Docplex CP minimize_static_lex issue
I'm currently utilizing docplex to optimize scheduling activities. My goal is to minimize both the makespan of my planning and the number of allocated workers. To achieve this, I've been utilizing the minimize_static_lex option, which has been quite effective.
However, I've encountered a scenario where, when optimizing my first objective alone (the number of workers), I immediately find a solution with 2 workers. Yet, when I incorporate the makespan into the lexicographic minimization, the solver only manages to find a solution with 5 workers. After 10 minutes, I ran out of patience, knowing that when minimizing the number of workers alone, a solution is found within 10 seconds.
I'm using the Python API. Is there any other approach I can take besides conducting a first optimization and then restarting a second one, adding a maximum constraint of 2 workers?
Second question: is there a way to update constraint during the solve ? I could allocate a period optimising the first objective alone, then fix it as a constraint and optimise the second one and so on. Ideally, I do not want to re-generate the model, just update a constraint.

With minimize_static_lex the following example works fine
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel
from docplex.cp.model import CpoParameters

mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')

param=CpoParameters()
param.OptimalityTolerance=0.01
mdl.set_parameters(param)

nbbus50 = mdl.integer_var(0,10,name='nbBus50')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(0,10,name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(0,10,name='nbBus30')
cost = mdl.integer_var(0,10000,name='cost')
co2emission = mdl.integer_var(0,10000,name='co2emission')

mdl.add(nbbus50*50+nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 200)
mdl.add(co2emission==nbbus50*10+nbbus40*11+nbbus30*12)
mdl.add(cost==nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400+nbbus50*625)
mdl.add(mdl.minimize_static_lex([cost,co2emission]))
msol=mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus50]," buses 50 seats") 
print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats") 
print(msol[cost])
print(msol[co2emission]/10) 

Let me translate into cpoptimizer the multi objective model zoo with several steps
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel
from docplex.cp.model import CpoParameters

mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')

param=CpoParameters()
param.OptimalityTolerance=0.01
mdl.set_parameters(param)

nbbus50 = mdl.integer_var(0,10,name='nbBus50')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(0,10,name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(0,10,name='nbBus30')
cost = mdl.integer_var(0,10000,name='cost')
co2emission = mdl.integer_var(0,10000,name='co2emission')

coef = mdl.integer_var(0,1,name='coef')

mdl.add(nbbus50*50+nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 200)
mdl.add(co2emission==nbbus50*10+nbbus40*11+nbbus30*12)
mdl.add(cost==nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400+nbbus50*625)


mdl.minimize(cost+coef*co2emission)
msol=mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus50]," buses 50 seats") 
print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats") 
print("cost=",msol[cost])
print("co2emission=",msol[co2emission]/10) 
print(msol[coef])

#let us not make the cost worse now

mdl.add(cost==msol[cost])
mdl.add(coef==1)


mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus50]," buses 50 seats") 
print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats") 
print("cost=",msol[cost])
print("co2emission=",msol[co2emission]/10) 

NB:
With OPL it's even easier since to make https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomultiobjective.mod work with CPOptimizer
   using CP;

    int nbKids=200;
    float costBus40=500;
    float costBus30=400;
    float costBus50=625;
         
    dvar int+ nbBus40 in 0..10;
    dvar int+ nbBus30 in 0..10;
    dvar int+ nbBus50 in 0..10;

    dvar int cost;
    dvar int co2emission;
         
    minimize
      staticLex(cost,co2emission);
         
    subject to
    {
     cost==costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
     co2emission==nbBus50*10+nbBus40*11+nbBus30*12;

      40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
    }

    execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
    {
      writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
      writeln("CO2 emission is ",co2emission/10);
      writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30,
      " 30 seats buses and ", nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
    }

